# Cannot find type Windows.UI.Xaml.Media.XamlLight in module Windows.winmd

Tags: xamarin, uwp, multitargeting

Building a Xamarin Forms App.
UWP gives the following error

Cannot find type Windows.UI.Xaml.Media.XamlLight in module Windows.winmd.

When trying to use the XamlLight Class within a multi-targeted class.

Visual Studio 16.2 issue with net core 3 preview using MSBuildSDKExtras for the multi targeting project.

any help would be greatly appreciated

Comment: What's your project's target version and min version?

Comment: Target and min UAP 10.0.16299. So the fix for the Windows.MD issue with the ambient light. was to reference the Windows.MD file directly in the UWP App project. C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\UnionMetadata\10.0.16299.0\Windows.winmd